# Is it possible to read text from a pdf using java FileReader or an alternative for java?

Tags: java, pdf

I am wanting to make a simple word counter for my latex documents so that I can double check my word count is accurate. More generally it is useful to discover whether java can interpret text from pdf files anyway. A google on it brought nothing up so I am thinking maybe not? If not, why?

Comment: As indicated by the answers,  there are libraries which can interpret text from PDF files.  Please be aware, though, that there are limits.  On the one hand it can be difficult to recognize multi column text as such.  On the other hand it can be hard to differentiate between gaps separating words and gaps for kerning purposes. Thus,  especially accurate word counts can be difficult.

Answer (score 4):

You can't read text from a .pdf without a *PDF* file reader.  Here are a couple of Java .pdf libraries:

- [Apache PDF Box](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)
- [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)

See also this link, for an example of Java text extraction with PDF Box:

- http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/text_extraction.html